# ParseError: bad input on line 5

Tags: python-3.6

```
score = raw_input("Enter Score: ")

try:
    s = float(score)

except:

    print "Error"

    quit()

if s >= 0.9:

    print "A"

elif s >= 0.8:

    print "B"

elif s >= 0.7:

    print "C"

elif s >= 0.6:

    print "D"

else:

    print "F"
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of quit() i recommend you to use sys.exit(0)

```
import sys 
score = raw_input("Enter Score: ")

try:
    s = float(score)

except:

    print "Error"

    sys.exit(0)

if s >= 0.9:

    print "A"

elif s >= 0.8:

    print "B"

elif s >= 0.7:

    print "C"

elif s >= 0.6:

    print "D"

else:

    print "F"
```

if you are using python 3 then use parenthesis with print function

** Best Way **

```
score=input()
try:
    s=float(score)
    if(s>=0.9):
        print("A")
    elif(s>=0.8):
        print("B")
    elif(s>=0.7)
        print("C)
except:
    print("error")
```